# React: How can this Pomodoro Clock pass the `freecodecamp tests 12 and 13`?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In this React Pomodoro clock, `setInterval` calls `down` every time `state.timeLeftSeconds` is reduced. However, when attempting to pass the freecodecamp tests 12 and 13, there is a message: `Break time didn't start with the correct value.: expected 60 to be at most 5`. Yet, when the clock is run the code appears to be working perfectly. Any help would be greatly appreciated. The testing suite is also there in the code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-fog-981wl

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './style.css';

/*
* A simple React component
*/
const initState = {
  breakLength: 5,
  sessionLength: 25,
  init: 'session',
  stateIndex: 0,
  timeLeft: undefined,
  timeLeftSeconds: undefined,
  started: false,
  intervalFunc: undefined
}

const states = [ { name: 'session', duration: 1500 }, { name: 'break', duration: 300 } ]

const secondsToMins = (time) => {
  let converted = ('0' + Math.floor(time / 60)).slice(-2) + ':' + ('0' + Math.floor(time % 60)).slice(-2);
  return converted;
}

class Clock extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = initState;
    this.breakDecrement = this.breakDecrement.bind(this);
    this.breakIncrement = this.breakIncrement.bind(this);
    this.sessionDecrement = this.sessionDecrement.bind(this);
    this.sessionIncrement = this.sessionIncrement.bind(this);
    this.startStop = this.startStop.bind(this);
    this.reset = this.reset.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let sessionSeconds = this.state.sessionLength * 60;
    this.setState({ timeLeftSeconds: sessionSeconds });
    this.setState({ timeLeft: secondsToMins(sessionSeconds) });
  }

  breakDecrement() {
    // decrements the breakLength and the breakSeconds
    // breakLength is only a number ie. 5 (does not show seconds)
    // breakSeconds is that nunber converted into seconds
    let breakLength = this.state.breakLength - 1;
    if (breakLength > 0 && breakLength < 61){
      this.setState({ breakLength: breakLength });
      let breakSeconds = breakLength * 60;
      states[1]['duration'] = breakSeconds;
    }
  }

  breakIncrement() {
    // same as decrement except does increment
    let breakLength = this.state.breakLength + 1;
    if (breakLength > 0 && breakLength < 61){
      this.setState({ breakLength: breakLength });
      let breakSeconds = breakLength * 60;
      states[1]['duration'] = breakSeconds;
    }
  }

  sessionDecrement() {
    // decrements the sessionLength and the sessionSeconds
    // sessionLength is only a number ie. 25 (does not show seconds)
    // sessionSeconds is that nunber converted into seconds
    let sessionLength = this.state.sessionLength - 1;
    if (sessionLength > 0 && sessionLength < 61){
      states[0]['duration'] = sessionLength*60;
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        sessionLength: prevState.sessionLength-1,
        timeLeftSeconds: (prevState.sessionLength-1)*60,
        timeLeft:  secondsToMins((prevState.sessionLength-1)*60)})
      );
    }
  }

  sessionIncrement() {
    // same as decrement except does increment
    let sessionLength = this.state.sessionLength + 1;
    if (sessionLength > 0 && sessionLength < 61){
      states[0]['duration'] = sessionLength*60;
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        sessionLength: prevState.sessionLength+1,
        timeLeftSeconds: (prevState.sessionLength+1)*60,
        timeLeft:  secondsToMins((prevState.sessionLength+1)*60)})
      );
    }
  }

  startStop(id) {
    // starts the countDown, which runs continuously until the start/stop button
    // is pressed again, which pauses the countdown.
    // the id parameter is used by countDown to play the audio beep
    if(!this.state.started){
      this.countDown(id);
      this.setState({ started: true});
    }
    // pauses the countDown
    if(this.state.started){
      let intervalFunc = this.state.intervalFunc;
      clearInterval(intervalFunc);
      this.setState({ started: false});
    }
  }

  reset() {
    let intervalFunc = this.state.intervalFunc;
    clearInterval(intervalFunc);
    // reset state to default values
    this.setState({ breakLength: 5 });
    this.setState({ sessionLength: 25 });
    this.setState({ init: 'session' });
    this.setState({ timeLeftSeconds: 1500})
    this.setState({ timeLeft: '25:00' });
    this.setState({ stateIndex: 0 });
    this.setState({ started: false });
    this.setState({ intervalFunc: undefined });
  }


  decreaseCurrentSecond = () => this.state.timeLeftSeconds--;

  countDown(id) {
    // set the function to a variable and set state to it, so the function
    // can be paused with clearInterval()
    var intervalFunc = setInterval(
      () => down(this.decreaseCurrentSecond()),
      1000
    );
    this.setState({ intervalFunc: intervalFunc });


    const down = (time) => {
      if (time > 0) {
        // converts seconds to MM:SS at every t-minus
        this.setState({ timeLeft: secondsToMins(time) });
        /*
        console.log(time);
        console.log(this.state.timeLeft);*/
      }

      let sound = document.getElementById(id).childNodes[0];

      if (time <= 0 ) {
        sound.play();
        this.setState({ timeLeft: secondsToMins(time) });

        console.log(time);
        console.log(this.stateIndex);
        console.log(this.state.init);
        console.log(this.state.timeLeftSeconds);

        let stateIndex = (this.state.stateIndex + 1) % states.length;
        this.setState({ stateIndex: stateIndex });
        this.setState({ init: states[stateIndex]['name'] });
        this.setState({ timeLeftSeconds: states[stateIndex]['duration'] });

        console.log(time);
        console.log(this.stateIndex);
        console.log(this.state.init);
        console.log(this.state.timeLeftSeconds);
      }
    };

    down(this.decreaseCurrentSecond());
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="clock">
      <h1 id="title">25-5 Clock</h1>

      <div>
      <p id="break-label">Break Length</p>
      <p id="break-length">{this.state.breakLength}</p>
      <button id="break-decrement" onClick={e => this.breakDecrement()}> Decrease </button>
      <button id="break-increment" onClick={e => this.breakIncrement()}> Increase </button>
      </div>

      <div>
      <p id="session-label">Session Length</p>
      <p id="session-length">{this.state.sessionLength}</p>
      <button id="session-decrement" onClick={e => this.sessionDecrement()}> Decrease </button>
      <button id="session-increment" onClick={e => this.sessionIncrement()}> Increase </button>
      </div>

      <hr/>

      <div>
      <p id="timer-label">{this.state.init}</p>
      <p id="time-left">{this.state.timeLeft}</p>
      <button id="start_stop" onClick={e => this.startStop(e.target.id)}><audio id="beep" src='./beep.mp3'></audio> start/stop </button>
      <button id="reset" onClick={e => this.reset()}> reset </button>
      </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
};

/*
* Render the above component into the div#app
*/
ReactDOM.render(<Clock />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>25-5 Clock</title>
  <style>
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <main>
    <div id="app"></app>
    </main>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason those tests are failing is because the `timeLeftSeconds` in the state isn't being set properly once the clock goes into the 'break' cycle and vice versa. I have made the necessary adjustments below. Notice the changes in the `decreaseCurrentSecond` and `down` methods.

Also, never try to update values in the state directly like you did here - `decreaseCurrentSecond = () => this.state.timeLeftSeconds--;`. This is not good practice - [Why can't I directly modify a component's state, really?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755997/why-cant-i-directly-modify-a-components-state-really)

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./style.css";

/*
 * A simple React component
 */
const initState = {
  breakLength: 0.5,
  sessionLength: 0.5,
  init: "session",
  // stateIndex: 0,
  timeLeft: undefined,
  timeLeftSeconds: undefined,
  started: false,
  intervalFunc: undefined
};

const secondsToMins = (time) => {
  let converted =
    ("0" + Math.floor(time / 60)).slice(-2) +
    ":" +
    ("0" + Math.floor(time % 60)).slice(-2);
  return converted;
};

class Clock extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = initState;
    this.breakDecrement = this.breakDecrement.bind(this);
    this.breakIncrement = this.breakIncrement.bind(this);
    this.sessionDecrement = this.sessionDecrement.bind(this);
    this.sessionIncrement = this.sessionIncrement.bind(this);
    this.startStop = this.startStop.bind(this);
    this.reset = this.reset.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let sessionSeconds = this.state.sessionLength * 60;
    this.setState({ timeLeftSeconds: sessionSeconds });
    this.setState({ timeLeft: secondsToMins(sessionSeconds) });
  }

  breakDecrement() {
    console.log("break decrement");
    // decrements the breakLength and the breakSeconds
    // breakLength is only a number ie. 5 (does not show seconds)
    // breakSeconds is that nunber converted into seconds
    let breakLength = this.state.breakLength - 1;
    if (breakLength > 0 && breakLength < 61) {
      this.setState({ breakLength: breakLength });
      // let breakSeconds = breakLength * 60;
      // states[1]["duration"] = breakSeconds;
    }
  }

  breakIncrement() {
    // same as decrement except does increment
    let breakLength = this.state.breakLength + 1;
    if (breakLength > 0 && breakLength < 61) {
      this.setState({ breakLength: breakLength });
      // let breakSeconds = breakLength * 60;
      // states[1]["duration"] = breakSeconds;
    }
  }

  sessionDecrement() {
    // decrements the sessionLength and the sessionSeconds
    // sessionLength is only a number ie. 25 (does not show seconds)
    // sessionSeconds is that nunber converted into seconds
    let sessionLength = this.state.sessionLength - 1;
    if (sessionLength > 0 && sessionLength < 61) {
      // states[0]["duration"] = sessionLength * 60;
      this.setState((prevState) => ({
        sessionLength: prevState.sessionLength - 1,
        timeLeftSeconds: (prevState.sessionLength - 1) * 60,
        timeLeft: secondsToMins((prevState.sessionLength - 1) * 60)
      }));
    }
  }

  sessionIncrement() {
    // same as decrement except does increment
    let sessionLength = this.state.sessionLength + 1;
    if (sessionLength > 0 && sessionLength < 61) {
      // states[0]["duration"] = sessionLength * 60;
      this.setState((prevState) => ({
        sessionLength: prevState.sessionLength + 1,
        timeLeftSeconds: (prevState.sessionLength + 1) * 60,
        timeLeft: secondsToMins((prevState.sessionLength + 1) * 60)
      }));
    }
  }

  startStop(id) {
    // starts the countDown, which runs continuously until the start/stop button
    // is pressed again, which pauses the countdown.
    // the id parameter is used by countDown to play the audio beep
    if (!this.state.started) {
      this.setState({ started: true });
      this.countDown(id);
    }
    // pauses the countDown
    if (this.state.started) {
      this.setState({ started: false });
      let intervalFunc = this.state.intervalFunc;
      clearInterval(intervalFunc);
    }
  }

  reset() {
    let intervalFunc = this.state.intervalFunc;
    clearInterval(intervalFunc);
    // reset state to default values
    this.setState({ breakLength: 5 });
    this.setState({ sessionLength: 25 });
    this.setState({ init: "session" });
    this.setState({ timeLeftSeconds: 1500 });
    this.setState({ timeLeft: "25:00" });
    // this.setState({ stateIndex: 0 });
    this.setState({ started: false });
    this.setState({ intervalFunc: undefined });
  }

  decreaseCurrentSecond = () =>
    //this.state.timeLeftSeconds--;
    {
      this.setState({
        timeLeftSeconds: this.state.timeLeftSeconds - 1
      });
      return this.state.timeLeftSeconds;
    };

  countDown(id) {
    // set the function to a variable and set state to it, so the function
    // can be paused with clearInterval()
    var intervalFunc = setInterval(
      () => down(this.decreaseCurrentSecond()),
      1000
    );
    this.setState({ intervalFunc: intervalFunc });

    const down = (time) => {
      if (time > 0) {
        // converts seconds to MM:SS at every t-minus
        this.setState({ timeLeft: secondsToMins(time) });
        /*
        console.log(time);
        console.log(this.state.timeLeft);*/
      }

      let sound = document.getElementById(id).childNodes[0];

      if (time <= 0) {
        sound.play();
        this.setState({ timeLeft: secondsToMins(time) });

        console.log(`##########`);
        console.log(time);
        // console.log(this.stateIndex);
        console.log(this.state.init);
        console.log(this.state.timeLeftSeconds);
        console.log(`##########`);

        // let stateIndex = (this.state.stateIndex + 1) % states.length;
        // this.setState({ stateIndex: stateIndex });
        this.setState({
          init: this.state.init === "session" ? "break" : "session"
        });
        this.setState({
          timeLeftSeconds:
            this.state.init === "session"
              ? this.state.sessionLength * 60 + 1
              : this.state.breakLength * 60 + 1
        });

        console.log(`##########`);
        console.log(time);
        // console.log(this.stateIndex);
        console.log(this.state.init);
        console.log(this.state.timeLeftSeconds);
        console.log(`##########`);
      }
    };

    // down(this.decreaseCurrentSecond());
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="clock">
        <h1 id="title">25-5 Clock</h1>

        <div>
          <p id="break-label">Break Length</p>
          <p id="break-length">{this.state.breakLength}</p>
          <button id="break-decrement" onClick={(e) => this.breakDecrement()}>
            {" "}
            Decrease{" "}
          </button>
          <button id="break-increment" onClick={(e) => this.breakIncrement()}>
            {" "}
            Increase{" "}
          </button>
        </div>

        <div>
          <p id="session-label">Session Length</p>
          <p id="session-length">{this.state.sessionLength}</p>
          <button
            id="session-decrement"
            onClick={(e) => this.sessionDecrement()}
          >
            {" "}
            Decrease{" "}
          </button>
          <button
            id="session-increment"
            onClick={(e) => this.sessionIncrement()}
          >
            {" "}
            Increase{" "}
          </button>
        </div>

        <hr />

        <div>
          <p id="timer-label">{this.state.init}</p>
          <p id="time-left">{this.state.timeLeft}</p>
          <button id="start_stop" onClick={(e) => this.startStop(e.target.id)}>
            <audio id="beep" src="./beep.mp3"></audio> start/stop{" "}
          </button>
          <button id="reset" onClick={(e) => this.reset()}>
            {" "}
            reset{" "}
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

/*
 * Render the above component into the div#app
 */
ReactDOM.render(<Clock />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-star-i3t8m?file=/src/index.js